# overpass "around" to find addresses in certain radius from a coordinate

Tags: python, typescript, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I would like to find the amount of registered addresses within a certain radius (lets say `radius=30` (meters) to a coordinate I input `(lat,lon)`. 
The code I'm looking for can be in either Python or Typescript.
I do not care if these are residential or business addresses.

I read that the 'around' function in the overpass API should be able to do this. Also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325973/how-can-i-find-all-nodes-around-a-point-that-are-members-of-a-way-with-a-certain) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606566/find-addresses-that-are-nearby-to-my-location) but did not really understand how to do it.

If there is a similar working solution using a different API (e.g. OSM) this would also work for me.

could you help please?

Comment: No, we cannot code it for you. Atleast make an effort then we can help.

Comment: As said before, please give us a Minimal Viable Answer. Also please give a link to the API's documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I should have provided some code.
Here is the solution in python:

```
def search_nearby_features(latitude, longitude, radius):
    overpass_url = "https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"
    query = f"""
    [out:json];
    (
      node(around:{radius},{latitude},{longitude});
      way(around:{radius},{latitude},{longitude});
      relation(around:{radius},{latitude},{longitude});
    );
    out center;
    """
    params = {
        "data": query
    }
    response = requests.get(overpass_url, params=params)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        return data["elements"]
    else:
        print("Error occurred:", response.text)
        return []
    
def get_node_points(nearby_features):
    nodes = []
    for point in nearby_features:
        if point['type'] == 'node':
            nodes.append(point)
    return nodes
```

just have to pick a lat, long and r values and then run:

```
nearby_features = search_nearby_features(latitude, longitude, radius)
nodes = get_node_points(nearby_features)
print(f"number of points\locations in a radius of {radius} meters from the given coordinates: {len(nodes)}")
```

note that I look specifically for type=='node' because these are address locations as far as I understood. I dont care about roads etc.